# Master thesis - new research topics

Tags: debris, ion-thruster

I am studying Aerospace master and currently on the brim to pursue my master thesis. I would like our input on the new research trends that are going on in the space industry. I would like to do some multidisciplinary work involving mechanical design, space system integration,  mechatronics, communication, nanosatellite, and propulsion. I am also fascinated by the space debris problem. I would really like any feedback on this. I am asking this question to keep myself current so when I get out I will have a career prospect.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very broad subject, but let me pick some "current" topics.

- there's very little "new original" ideas involving space travel that are remotely viable (technologically, economically or politically). A lot of entirely new designs will be needed for Mars landing, and there are some unresolved challenges involving Breakthrough Starshot, but the rest of work is pretty much incremental on existing designs. Of course if you do have some entirely original ideas, there's nothing stopping you, but there's likely no "next big thing right out the door" to pick up. (EM Drive might be one, but it might be just a bunch of snake oil as well.)
- since you're into communications, one of unresolved problems for Breakthrough Starshot is communication at ~4 light years distance. Nobody really has any good idea how to achieve that. The general "hunch" is it should be doable but all current solutions fall woefully short of the goal.
- and then, the incremental work is important. The focus is on reduction of costs, reduction of power consumption, mass, improving reliability, streamlining production, miniaturization, and turning experimental designs into production equipment.

---

- mechanical design, mechatronics

Since all larger payloads (and many small) unfold like origami, there's quite a bit of that in spacecraft; especially passive systems (which are usually very fault-proof and inexpensive) are valuable. Reaction wheels and CMGs are still bulky, heavy, expensive, power-hungry and fault-prone. There's a lot of room for improvement in that area. And every device working in vacuum, or on vacuum-air interface is a challenge. Plus of course all robots and rovers, that's a good bit of a current challenge. We "have a general clue" how to do all of that, but getting the details ironed out is an awful lot of work.

- space system integration

I can't tell you much on that. There's a lot of integration on ad-hoc basis: adapting given booster for given launch stage, given payload for given launcher, given part or piece of software for given purpose. There are some standards and some standarization efforts, but it's still mostly a big zoo where integration is a Sisyphean work, of getting thousands of mismatched available systems to work together. You can certainly find a job with it, but I don't particularly see any master thesis topics.

- communication

A whole big field with constant room for improvement. I'm not really into it so I can't give you much detail, but if there's a field to find "something completely new", it's likely here.

- nanosatellite

Miniaturization, reduction of cost and power consumption. It's a big game because there are a lot of customers for these, and a lot of promising designs that are simply too big. A huge area, pick any system found on big satellites and not on cubesats, and adapt it.

- propulsion.

Besides bringing a few designs out of lab and into space, and un-mothballing several older promising designs that were put on hold by the end of Cold War, the game is the same - improve, miniaturize, reduce inefficiencies, simplify to reduce price, streamline manufacturing etc. Lots of work in that direction, and a lot of good research - replacing active subsystems with passive, better control algorithms, creative material engineering, etc.

As for debris, there are a couple projects to combat them, although their practical and economical viability is somewhat dubious. Regardless, even though likely not a single piece of debris will be deorbited as result, that's certainly a subject that can provide ground for quite a few good scientific publications and a stable job at a research institute ;)

Comment: thanks for such quick comment and it very valuable. I really like the debris comment and yes we need to definitely look at the debris more seriously and there are some commercial companies that are boasting de-orbiting but the results are yet unknown.

Comment: @AM: Debris is a problem that solves itself if we only don't produce more. Big pieces aren't a problem as they are mapped and can be avoided. It's the countless little scattered bits that are too small to detect that pose a real danger, and without good detection, all ideas like lasers to deorbit them are just a bunch of hookey.